How to handle graphics output with Container2WASM
I wanted to see if container2WASM could compile a docker container containing a game like Speed Dreams (open source racing game) to WASM. I am unsure however how to output the graphics from the container once I eventually compile it to WASM with container2WASM. Is this possible? I noticed that container2WASM's online demos include a visual terminal of the container using xterm. How could I accomplish something similar with my docker container of Speed Dreams?
Some additional info: when the container is executed in docker desktop, it attempts to run Speed Dreams but outputs this error:
2024-07-12 10:59:14 error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
2024-07-12 10:59:14 00:00:00.051 Default  Error   Couldn't initialize SDL audio/video sub-system (No available video device)
2024-07-12 10:59:14 Exiting from Speed Dreams after some error occurred (see above).
Will this be resolved if I can figure out how to handle the SDL output from the container after compiling it to WASM?
